# Is it possible to create multiple cache stores using Spring's cache abstraction with redis?

Tags: spring, caching, spring-mvc, redis

I'm developing a web application using Spring MVC and I'm using using spring's cache abstraction with Redis to cache my database queries. But I am not able to create multiple cache stores using `@Cacheable`.

```
@Cacheable("acache")
public String atest(int i) {
   return "a";
}

@Cacheable("bcache")
public String btest(int i) {
   return "b";
}

...
...
String s = atest(1);
String r = btest(1);
```

Using redis, both `s` and `r` have the same value "`a`". Even though I cache the two methods in different caches, it seems to have no effect.

But this works fine when I use Spring's `SimpleCacheManager`.

Spring bean configuration for Redis:

```
<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:hostName="${redis.host-name}"
        p:port="${redis.port}"
        p:usePool="true"/>


<bean id="redisTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
        p:connectionFactory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>

<bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
        c:template-ref="redisTemplate">
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you show your Spring beans configuration?

Comment: Beans configuration added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the docs the RedisCacheManager by default saves the keys directly, without appending a prefix (cache name, which acts as a namespace). To change it and avoid clashes set 'usePrefix' to 'true': http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.html