# Downside of many caches in spring

Tags: spring, caching, redis

Due to the [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460606/how-do-i-use-the-key-in-a-condition-in-cacheable-annotation/32485382#32485382) of not being able to evict entries based on a partial key, I am thinking of a workaround using the cache name as my partial key and evicting all (there would only be one) entries in the cache. For example, let's say there are 2 key-value pairs like so:

"123@name1" -> value1,
"124@name2" -> value2

Ideally, at the time of eviction, I would like to remove all keys that contain the string "123". However, as this is not supported, the workaround I'm thinking of is to have the following:

"123" cache: "name1" -> value1

"124" cache: "name2" -> value2

Then at eviction, I would simply specify to remove all keys in "123" cache

The downside of this of course is that there would be a lot of different caches. Is there any performance penalty to this?

From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145372/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-cache-stores-using-springs-cache-abstraction), it seems Redis at least only uses the cache name as a prefix. So it is not creating multiple separate caches underneath it. But I would like to verify my understanding.

I am also looking to use Redis as my underlying cache provider if that helps.

Comment: No penalty from Redis side. From Spring (by the links you provided I assume you're talking about it ) side I don't know.

Comment: @Imaskar Could you please elaborate on why no penalty from Redis side? Is it as indicated above the cache name is just a prefix?

Comment: I mean cached values will be just keys in Redis and key retrieval in Redis is constant time. How many technical keys does spring-data-redis use I don't know and can't check right now. Too busy, sorry.

Comment: Take a look at `redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(cache_name, cache_key, data)`. This is what p1 of @DhruvPathak's answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use few approaches to overcome this :

1. **Use grouped [data structures](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) like sets, sorted sets and hashes** : Each one of them supports really high number of member elements. So you can use them to store your cache items,and do the relevant lookups. However, do go through the performance difference ( would be very small ) on this kind of lookup compared to a direct key-value lookup.
   Once you want to evict a group of cache keys which are of similar type, you just remove that data structure key from redis.
2. **Use redis database numbers** : You would need to edit redis.conf to increase maximum number of redis database numbers possible. Redis databases are just numbers which provide namespacing in which your key-values can lie. To group similar items, you would put them in the same database number, and empty the database with a single command whenever you want to flush that group of keys.
   The caveat here is that, though you would be able to use same redis connection, you would have to switch databases through redis [SELECT](https://redis.io/commands/select) command

Comment: To overcome what?

Comment: Overcome partial/pattern based eviction of multiple keys

Comment: How would a grouped data structure work in terms of storing into and retrieving the cache? For example, let's say the key "123" points to a set in the cache. How would I annotate my method to indicate the result of my method needs to be added into this set (instead of replacing it which would be the default behavior)

Comment: All grouped data structures support key lookups for elements inside them

Comment: Except you can't set individual expiration times for elements.

Comment: @Imaskar Yes, that caveat is there, but I assumed that OP wanted bulk expiration which can be done by expiring the grouped data.