# How to check Cache Hit Ratio of every cache values in redis?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using the Redis configuration with Spring framework. There are multiples API's for which there are different values of cache like below :

```
@Cacheable(value = "API1")
@Cacheable(value = "API2")
```

now by using the below command

> redis-cli info stats

I can get keyspace hits but how to calculate hits of different cache values (like specifically for value = "API1")?

Comment: Look at SpringBoot Actuator

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide more information/code so others can replicate your problem if you expect to receive a reply.

Comment: Take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145372/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-cache-stores-using-springs-cache-abstraction.